# saving inputs from pagedown editor in the database

Tags: javascript, database, laravel-4, pagedown

I am using pagedown editor to replace textarea in an app i'm building but when i get sample codes as input from the editor and save it in the database, querying it out gives the result without any formatting.
I was expecting the result to the same as the preview of pagedown editor.

this is the form

```
                 {{Form::open(array('url'=>'profile/askquestion'))}}
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Title</label>
                      <div class="">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="title" value="{{ Input::old('title') != NULL ? Input::old('title') : '' }}" placeholder="What's your programming question? Be specific." autofocus>
                        <span class="badge alert-danger">{{ ($errors->has('title') ? $errors->first('title') : '') }}</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label"></label>
                      <div class="wmd-panel1">
                        <div id="wmd-button-bar-second" class="pagedown-swag"></div>
                        <textarea class="wmd-input form-control" name="body" id="wmd-input-second" rows="10"></textarea>
                        <span class="badge alert-danger">{{ ($errors->has('body') ? $errors->first('body') : '') }}</span>
                      </div><br ><hr>

                      <div id="wmd-preview-second" class="wmd-preview"></div><hr>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Post Your Question</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              {{Form::close()}}
```

code for saving in the database

```
public function postAskquestion(){
    $registerData = Input::all();
    $registerRules = array(
        'title'     =>'required',
        'body'      =>'required',
        );
    $registerValidator = Validator::make($registerData,$registerRules);
    if($registerValidator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($registerValidator);
    }
    if( $registerValidator->passes()) {
        $question = new Question();
        $question->title = Input::get('title');
        $question->description = Input::get('body');
        $question->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $question->save();


        return Redirect::to('/')->with('alertMessage',"question posted successfully.");
    }

}
```

code for querying the contain

```
Route::get('question/{id}/{slug}', function ($id, $slug) {

$data['question'] = Question::find($id);

    return View::make('site.question')->with($data);
```

});

code for displaying the contain

```
<div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel1 wmd-preview">{{$question->description}}</div>
```

Help please

Comment: Could you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post but here is how I am doing it

I'm saving the html from `wmd-preview` and save it with ajax

**jQuery**

```
var value = $("#wmd-preview).html();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to-your-php-file",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {value: value} //The first value is the variable that you're sending to PHP
})
```

**PHP**

```
CONNECT TO YOUR DATABASE

$value = $_POST['value];
$query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO posts VALUES('$value'));
```